# ¿como sustituir un punto por un espacio en el nombre de una columna de r?

Tags: r, dataframe

Tengo un dataframe en el que los nombres de las columnas me aparecen separados por puntos y quiero separarlos por espacios. He probado con el siguiente comando pero no me funciona:

`data%>%str_replace('.', "")`

Comment: Prueba con: `colnames(data) <- gsub("[.]", " ", colnames(data))`